# Размер шрифта в TextFormField через ThemeData

Tags: flutter, dart

Не могу понять как изменить размер шрифта у `TextFormField` через `ThemeData`.

Мой `main.dart`

```dart
void main() {
    runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MapPage(),
    theme: ThemeData
    (
      inputDecorationTheme:
        InputDecorationTheme
        (
          labelStyle:
            TextStyle
            (
              fontSize: 30.0,
            ),
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.black12,
          border: OutlineInputBorder()
        )
    ),
  ));
}
```

Я правильно понимаю, что за текст в TextFormField отвечает `labelStyle`? У меня не изменяется размер шрифта.

Comment: В `TextFormField` есть поле `TextStyle style`, он отвечает за стиль текста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала определяем нужные нам стили в MaterialApp.

```
theme: ThemeData(
  primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(
  headline1: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.blue,
    fontSize: 13.0,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
    fontFamily: 'RobotoBold',
  ),
```

Затем применяем его к тексту.

```
Text(
  'SALE\n-50%',
  style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline1,
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
),
```

Если хотите использовать тот же стиль из темы, но с другим цветом, то можете так:

```
Text(
  'SALE\n-50%',
  style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline3!.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
),
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Получается надо явно указывать какой стиль нужно использовать. Тогда непонятно для чего используется InputDecorationTheme. В нем работают только рамки, цвета и наверное еще что-то, но только не шрифты. С ними вообще никак. Опять же странно.... TextTheme у меня работает прекрасно. Вот так тоже работает в TextFormField: 
      TextTheme
        (
          bodyText2: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
          button: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
          headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0, color: Colors.black)
      ),

Comment: TextFormField(
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,)

Comment: А если дальше шагнуть, то можно тему в отдельный файл вынести? Рано или поздно мне прилетит дизайн и там будет большая такая тема.

Answer (score 0):

[labelStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecorationTheme/labelStyle.html) задает стиль метки для пустого поля. Если поле заполнено, то применяется стиль [floatingLabelStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecorationTheme/floatingLabelStyle.html).